# Pushing jQuery plugin input value to a model in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

**Situation:**
I'm porting over, or should I say *attempting* to port Lakshan Perera's Simple jQuery ColorPicker (https://github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker) over to Angular. After reviewing similar problems on SO it seems like some folks assign the scope of the plugin through the controller, but the proper (Angular) way to do this is by wrapping the plug-in in a directive. I'm getting close. I'm able to properly render the plug-in in my view via my new custom attribute, but I'm not sure how to set up the directive to pass the input value to attribute's value (an ng-model). The actual input updates, but the Angular isn't listening for a change and so is in effect unaware that the input value has been updated. The official documentation talks about setting up custom attributes here (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), but I still was unable to figure out how to I actually watch a change in the element and then push that value to the attribute's value.

**Desired functionality -**

```
<input my-widget="{{color}}" type="text"/> <!-- my-widget instantiates my directive -->
<h1 style="color:{{color}}"></h1>          <!-- I would like the input value to dump into the attribute's value, in this case {{color}} -->
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
app.directive('myWidget', function(){
    var myLink = function(scope, element, attr) {

        scope.$watch('element',function(){

            var value = element.val();

            element.change(function(){

             console.log(attr.ngModel); // This is currently logging undefined

                     // Push value to attr here? 

                console.log( value + ' was selected');
            });
        });

        var element = $(element).colorPicker();
    }

    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: myLink
    }   

});
```

**Question:**
How the heck do I set up the attribute value to catch the element's updated value?

Comment: In addition to the fiddle below I have also thrown this into a repo on Github which is available here - https://github.com/Swordfish0321/AngularJS-Color-Picker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would implement it like this:

```
app.directive('colorPicker', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      color: '=colorPicker'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.colorPicker({
        // initialize the color to the color on the scope
        pickerDefault: scope.color,
        // update the scope whenever we pick a new color
        onColorChange: function(id, newValue) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.color = newValue;
          });
        }
      });

      // update the color picker whenever the value on the scope changes
      scope.$watch('color', function(value) {
        element.val(value);
        element.change();                
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You'd use it like so:

```
<input color-picker="color">
```

Here is a working jsFiddle, with a few little widgets to toy with: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/x2uwQ/

The jsFiddle uses an isolate scope to bind a scope value `color` to whatever was passed in to the `color-picker` attribute. We `$watch` the expression `'color'` to see when this value changes, and update the color picker appropriately.

Comment: First of all, you sir rock, this is exactly what I was trying to do. But I'm curious your 'onColorChange' method...did you just make this up? I went through the actual plug in and saw the actual change is made on 'changeColor', I kept trying to pass through that to no avail. Or does naming convention not even matter? I mean this is more of a javascript question than an Angular question–To use your example would it be the same if I said `method: function(id, a) {scope.$apply(function(){scope[attrs.colorPicker] = a;});}`

Comment: I really tried to avoid asking on SO because I wanted to figure this out on my own. I just want to make sure I fully understand rather than merely trolling for something to copy and paste. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: I got the `onColorChange` method from [the readme](https://github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker#options), in the section named "Color Change Callback". The names of the arguments, however, don't matter (e.g. `a` is okay). Happy to have helped!

Comment: Nice, yeah when I looked back at the jquery.colorpicker.js file I was missing the selectorOwner.data('onColorChange').call(selectorOwner, $(selectorOwner).prev("input").attr("id"), value); line. *I probably deleted it on accident moving some stuff around. My app is wired to a mongo backend so rather than my model being {{headerColor}} its {{project.headerColor}}. If I add the **project.** it breaks the link, any ideas on how you would extend this to parse a model that is within a data object?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the jsFiddle to use an isolate scope. That's technically the right way to do it; the only reason I didn't start with this method is there's a bug in Angular (I've mentioned it in a comment in the jsFiddle source code).

Comment: Since jQuery is included (and it is included before Angular) element is already wrapped in jQuery, so there's no need to call angular.element(element).  I made an edit to reflect this.  I also edited your post to make it clear that the use of attrs.colorPicker applied to the previous version of the fiddle... where an isolate scope was not used.  It was very instructive for me to be able to see both versions -- one without and one with isolate scope -- thanks.

Comment: Good call on both accounts!