# How to get reference to model property by knowing it's path in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new with angular js, situation is this: I have javascript datepicker, which is input with popup for date selection, input is bound to angular model.

Problem as I understand is that input value is changed from javascript, not from ui, so angular js does not know, that value has changed, so it does not update model value.

I've found [sample with color picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577983/pushing-jquery-plugin-input-value-to-a-model-in-angularjs), it would almost fit, except the fact, that I don't wish to hardcode what property to update.

I would imagine following workflow:
   1. subscribe to all datepickers' `onchanged` event
   2. when that event is fired, read model path from input (for example reading ng-model attribute value, may be there's better way?)
   3. and use that path to update value in model. I could split path by using dot and access property using those parts, but I somehow think, that this should be already implemented in angular js (at least in inner routines).

Comment: Where is the hard coding in the answer provided it allows any property to be assigned to color-picker directive.

Comment: As I've mentioned in question, I don't wish to hardcode exact property in event handler, I have multiple datepickers in page bound to different parts of the model, don't wish to write event handling for each explicitly.

Comment: No there is no hardcoding in the directive at all. The color property defined in the directive scope gets its intial value from the directive invocation in html. So if you have to use this directive at multiple places you would do `color-picker="myColor1".... color-picker="myColor2"` and so on.

Comment: @Chandermani - oh I see now, still have to get used to the fact, that scope depends on context :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$scope.$apply` to inform AngularJS about the model change. I don't know which datepicker you really use, but may i can be look something like:

```
$($element).datepicker({
  .
  .
  .
}).on('changeDate', function(event){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.date = event.date;  
  });
});
```

More about `$apply` in the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) and in my opinion an [excellent article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) from Jim Hoskins.

Comment: I don't wish to tell explicitly, that my model has property `date`. What if I'm attaching datepicker with `$('.date').datepicker()` and have properties like `project.creationDate`, `project.currentMilestone.deadlineDate` - that means many datepickers in page, all bound to different parts of model.

Comment: I suggest creating a directive for your datepicker that handles the event subscription to the 'changeDate' event and also permits you to pass in the model attributes you wish to target the results of the picked date. For example, <div data-my-datepicker="deadlineDate"></div> . You will need to use $scope.$apply(...) as @tschiela recommended above to reach back into AngularJS $scope.

Answer (score 0):

@Chandermani correctly noticed, that in color picker example I've mentioned, you can specify property to bind to in html, so it solves situation I've described.

Anyway I've looked up into source code of angular js and noticed, that `$apply` is much more clever than I thought, so answering to my question title, you can give complex expressions to `$apply`, like assignments:

```
 $('.date').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
       var input = $(e.target).find('input');
       var currentScope = angular.element(input).scope();

       // exp will evaluate to something model.createdDate = '2013-08-06'
       var exp = input.attr('ng-model') + '="' + input.val() + '"';
       currentScope.$apply(exp);
    });
```